# feedly sandbox and oauth.io

Tags: oauth, oauth.io, feedly

A big thanks to the OAuth.io team for all of the efforts towards providing a easy to deploy solution for OAuth.  I just tried to integrate the feedly sandbox key and secret  (found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/feedly-cloud/ZNn0UUOyCZw)) in order to test the integration of said API.  I have gotten only errors for the 4th time now.  I am getting:

```
{
"errorCode":400, 
"errorId":"sandbox-he.2015070222.2091404", 
"errorMessage":"unknown scope:https://sandbox.feedly.com/subscriptions"
}
```

Is this something OAuth.io is supporting?  Do they intend for the sandbox version to work?   Having the sandbox version working would seem to align with the workflow for feedly apps.

Answer (score 0):

the scope for the sandbox is the same as the production:

```
https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions
```

[source](https://developer.feedly.com/v3/auth/)